# What is the cause for Error HRESULT: 0x800A03EC?

Tags: c#, excel, error-handling, console-application, taskscheduler

I am getting an Error:

> "FileReader; Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

when I run my console application through task scheduler. But I don't get any error when I run it manually. I am not sure if this is an access issue or programming issue.

> Note: I do not have admin access on the server that I am running this
>   program.

I have tried to search for reason, but I have not found anything which resembles my scenario.

I am not sure which part of the code is causing this issue, so I am not sharing any code here.

Comment: Can you please provide source code and examples?

Comment: Hey Treant, I cant give you the code. sorry.

Comment: @VinayakJakati Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue. Works fine when it is run manually, via command prompt, and via a shell script. Just wouldn't work for task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

The error code 0x800A03EC (or -2146827284) means NAME_NOT_FOUND; in other words, you've asked for something, and Excel can't find it.

But sometimes, just sometimes, the service throw out the exception "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" while it's trying to get range with cell's name.

Comment: Thank you for the explaining the error meaning. Could you please tell me how is it that the same code runs fine when I run it manually? I only get this error when the code is run by the task scheduler.